# How to cache a view for all users of a role?

Tags: 8, views, caching

I have a view that displays a map. I need to display 7000 entries on the map.
I have installed solar search API to index the content and have created a view using that.
Still, the loading time for that view is around 1 minute for each user. After the first fetch, then it loads fast for that user since it fetches the data from the cache.

I was wondering whether I can cache the entire view for all users of a specific role.
I tried installing the "[Views Custom Cache Tags](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_custom_cache_tag)" module.
But I am a bit lost on how to configure it.
Also not sure whether this will solve my problem or not.

Suggestions, please.

Comment: Cache tags won't help here, this is about cache contexts. Default is a context for the hashed user permissions, which is exactly what you want. A cache context for the specific user is only added when there is such a dependency. Then you have to remove this dependency and render it separately.

Comment: Thank You. It helped. How do we know whether there is any such dependency for a specific user or not? I am displaying users list on the map. And there are exposed filters for the view. Is this the reason?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether a filter is exposed, it does, however, matter if you set a default value depending on the current user. Similar the users list, it is not necessarily depending on the current user, but it possibly could.

Comment: I played with this a bit. Created two views - one with exposed filter and the second one without any exposed filter.   The second view was cached as expected. So my conclusion is exposed filter forces each user to load the view completely from scratch. The cache is discarded. Once more observation is when the user logs in again then also the cache is discarded.

Comment: An exposed filter forces each URL to load the view completely from scratch.

Comment: But that is not what I observed. Loading different URL's from scratch is fine. But the same URL (for example the landing page of the view) is loaded from scratch for each user with the same role. In the database as well, I can see an additional raw in the 'cache_data' table, whenever a new user accesses the landing page of the view.

Comment: I'm not sure a view can really be cached per role. What if you have a user with 2 roles assigned which cache should they receive? Views has got to be kept flexible to handle common use cases so that's probably why per role might not work

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question title and the [comment of @Leigh](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295377/how-to-cache-a-view-for-all-users-of-a-role#comment372643_295377), without going into the details of the complexity of the specific View:

> How to cache a view for all users of a role?

Views are cached like any other rendered content. When rendered a View bubbles up the cacheable metadata of Views plugins, like filter or sorting plugins and the rendered content itself.

Additionally there are the three default contexts, as defined in the service container:

*core.services.yml:*

```
  required_cache_contexts: ['languages:language_interface', 'theme', 'user.permissions']
```

The context `user.permissions` is a hash of all of the user's permissions, which is the result of the roles assigned to a user.

So in the end a View is cached for user roles by default.

Comment: Thanks this was what I was hinting at but didn't have time to explain fully. The cache would need to be a culmination of each user's roles/permissions. Slight tweak to your answer should `is a hash of all user permissions` actually be something like `is a hash of all of the user's permissions`?